# StoreFront Footer Widgets Side by Side

Tags: css, wordpress, storefront

I have recently downloaded Woocommerce within Wordpress and I am using the StoreFront theme to try and learn how to put an ecommerce site together. I have managed to add products/categories etc. Where I am stuck is trying to display widgets within the footer to appear side by side just above the copyright bar.

At present I have added 4 widgets and they all appear on top of each other, and I'm not sure how I can have these within columns.

How can I go about doing that?

An example of a footer bar that I am trying to build is shown below:
http://flatsome.uxthemes.com/

I currently have the latest version of Wordpress, StoreFront, Woocommerce.

Thanks guys for your replies and updates.

I have added the code of what i have from my view source (sorry not sure what to copy from the wordpress backend)

```
<div class="sfb-footer-bar">
<div class="col-full">
<section id="text-2" class="widget-1 widget-first widget-odd widget 
widget_text"><h2 class="widget-title">Get In Touch</h2>         
<div class="textwidget">My Domain Ltd<br/>
            01234 56789<br/>
            info@mydomain.com<br/>
            Email Us Today and we will respond within 24 hours!<br/>
            </div>
                    </section><section id="text-4" class="widget-2 widget-even widget widget_text"><h2 class="widget-title">Latest Posts</h2>           <div class="textwidget">Testing Area 2</br>
            Testing Area 2</br>
            Testing Area 2</br>
            Testing Area 2</div>
                    </section><section id="text-5" class="widget-3 widget-last widget-odd widget widget_text"><h2 class="widget-title">WHERE CAN I SEE YOU</h2>         <div class="textwidget">JFKLSDJKFJDSJL</div>
                    </section></div></div>
                <footer id="colophon" class="site-footer" role="contentinfo">
                    <div class="col-full">

                            <div class="site-info">
                    &copy; My Domain 2015   </div><!-- .site-info -->

                    </div><!-- .col-full -->
                </footer><!-- #colophon -->
```

Comment: Please update your question to include the code that you have so far

Comment: There are tags for wordpress, woocommerce, etc. I added them so you will attract more answers, but I had to delete some of the old tags that I thought was irrelevant to stay within the five tag limit.

Comment: I think the WooCommerce tag is also kind of irrelevant since the question is about CSS alignment.

Comment: Storefront has 4 different footer widget areas. Put a widget in each and they will appear as columns. This is the storefront default as you can see [here](http://tinyurl.com/pdvr3mg)

Comment: Thank you helgatheviking, for some reason i thought i tried that but i guess not